# How to set array key as it's index in javascript/node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

I have an array of objects like this :

```
var kvArray = [ 
   { 
       number: '123',
       duration: '00:00:00' 
   },
   { 
      number: '324',
      duration: '00:00:00' 
   }]
```

I want to generate a new array from the above array such that the `number` key becomes the index.

This is what I tried

```js
var kvArray = [
   { 
       number: '123',
       duration: '00:00:00' 
   },
   { 
       number: '324',
       duration: '00:00:00' 
   }]

var reformattedArray = kvArray.map(obj =>{ 
   var rObj = {};
   rObj[obj.number] = obj.duration;
   return rObj;
});
console.log(reformattedArray)
```

The above output looks like this in the console with 0 and 1 as the index:
[image]

Instead I want the output array to be like this :

```
123: {"00:00:00"}
324: {"00:00:00"}
```

such that instead of 0 , 1 as the index I have 123 and 324 as the index.
So that if write test_array[123] in my code I should be able to get 00:00:00 in the output. Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do here?
Suggest better ways how this can be done

How do I do this?

Comment: Logically the curly bracket means an object, and you can't create an object without a key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array#map` with `Object.assign()` to create the desired output.

```js
const data = [ { number: '123', duration: '00:00:00' }, { number: '324', duration: '00:00:00' } ],
      result = Object.assign(...data.map(({number, duration}) => ({[number]: duration})));
      
console.log(result);
```

Comment: (side note): keys should be numeric according to the OP's output, so the key should be casted to a number.

Comment: Keys are meant to be string in an object, if keys are numeric one should use Map.

Comment: Euuh okay, as you wish, it's just that the answer would be completer in a such a way, to me ;).

Answer (score 2):

In case `number` values will be unique in your array, you can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a map object like shown below:

```js
const data = [
  { number: '123', duration: '00:00:00' },
  { number: '324', duration: '00:00:00' }
];      
    
const map = data.reduce((r, { number:k, duration:v }) => (r[k] = v, r), {});

console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reformattedArray =[]
tempHash = kvArray.reduce(function(i,j){
    return $.extend(i,j)
})
for(i in tempHash) {
    reformattedArray[i] = tempHash[i]
}
```